# Calling EnvelopeDocumentTabs: create returns an error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm automatization the process of create tabs in a document using the EnvelopeDocumentTabs: create, but, when i made the request, return an error that i couldn't find in the documentation of DocuSign, i would like to know how i can fixe this.

Request body:

```
{
  "signHereTabs": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "pageNumber": "4",
      "xPosition": "500",
      "yPosition": "625"
    }
  ]
}
```

Error Return:

```
{
    "errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
    "message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. Updated tabs must all be Strikethrough or SmartSection tabs if you're not specifying a valid recipient."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the recipient you're specifying may not be valid. Please share your entire JSON. Sometimes the issue may lie in a different part of your request body, but the error message pops up when the backend is processing the inner childs.

I am happy to take a look if you can share your payload JSON. Thank you